# Can you load a XAP from a byte array in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mef, xap, dynamic-loading

I know that MEF currently supports downloading XAP files from a URI (which is awesome!), but does anyone know if it's possible to have MEF load a XAP from a byte array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is in fact what DeploymentCatalog does.  And since the source code to MEF is available ([mef.codeplex.com](http://mef.codeplex.com)), you can just refer to that.  The code you are looking for is in src\Composition.Initialization\System\ComponentModel\Composition\Hosting\Package.cs.  The LoadPackagedAssemblies takes a stream (of a XAP) and returns the assemblies in it.